# Determine whether an email is about to be send without customizing the vanilla send button

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I need to determine *on client side* whether an email record is about to be send. In addition, I rather not customizing the vanilla send button.
Is there a way to do it?

My scenario: I need to display a message to the user on send, but not on reply or on forward. Currently, the message is displayed `onSave` like so:

```
var SAVE_MODES = { SEND: 7 };
function onSave (eContext) {
   if (eContext.getEventArgs().getSaveMode() == SAVE_MODES.SEND) {
      displayMyMessage();
   }
}
```

However, the condition evaluates to true not only on send, but also on reply, and on forward, which is undesired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, simply check against the value of `statecode`. If it's value is `0` (i.e, open), display the message (else, the email is on a state wherein the "reply" and the "forward" buttons are displayed).